# Yii check if homepage

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

Is there a buildin method or property in Yii to check if page is homepage?

I know i can use something like this:

```
$controller = Yii::app()->getController();
$isHome = $controller->getAction()->getId() === 'index' ? true : false;
```

Or put it in a method in main controller, but i am looking for something cleaner.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If You want to check the current page, ie action is the default of the current controller..

```
$controller = Yii::app()->getController();
$isHome = $controller->action->id === $controller->defaultAction->id ? true : false;
```

> dafeultaction may not always be 'index', it can be changed, so you
>   need to compare it with defaultAction instead..

And by homepage if you mean the defult page of site, then you need to compare your controller also with `defaultController`..

```
$controller = Yii::app()->getController();
$default_controller = Yii::app()->defaultController;
$isHome = (($controller->id === $default_controller->id) && ($controller->action->id === $controller->defaultAction->id)) ? true : false;
```

In Yii2:

```
$controller = Yii::$app->controller;
$default_controller = Yii::$app->defaultRoute;
$isHome = (($controller->id === $default_controller) && ($controller->action->id === $controller->defaultAction)) ? true : false;
```

Comment: In my case, the code is:

`$controller = Yii::app()->getController();
$isHome = $controller->action->id === $controller->defaultAction ? true : false;`

Answer (score 6):

This is what I use to check if I'm on the frontpage:

```
$isFrontpage = false;
if ((Yii::app()->controller->getId().'/'.Yii::app()->controller->getAction()->getId()) == 'site/index'  ) { 
    $isFrontpage = true;
}
```

Works like a charm.... even on views...

Answer (score 2):

May be this help you:)

```
<?php
  $controllerl = Yii::$app->controller;
  $homecheker = $controllerl->id.'/'.$controllerl->action->id;
  if($homecheker=='site/index')
  {
     //no border on home page
     $mymaincls ='main-nav navbar-fixed-top';
  }else
  {
     //border all other page
     $mymaincls ='main-nav navbar-fixed-top header-border';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

if by 'homepage' you mean 'frontpage' then you can check [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pisfrontpage/) that does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

you could check the homepage using the extension pageChecker:

```
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pagechecker
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about this extension? A link alone is a bit little to answer a question.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare the current controller and action with the default controller and action.

```
$controller = Yii::app()->getController();

$default_controller = Yii::app()->defaultController;

$isHome = $controller->getId() === $default_controller && $controller->getAction()->getId() === 'index';
```

i couldn't access default action via **Yii::app()** like **Yii::app()->defaultController**. however you use string to compare.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$check_home=$path=='site/index.html'?'TRUE':'False';

$path=Yii::$app->request->pathInfo;
```

do as per your logic if check_home is true or false

i am removing my sidebars on home page

Comment: //in YII2

//this will work 

 //this will check if home page or not

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Url::current() == '/index.php?r=site%2Findex' || Url::current() == Url::home()){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace common\helpers;

class Url extends \yii\helpers\Url
{
    public static function isHome()
    {
        return (self::home() == Yii::$app->request->url);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.