# is_home() function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

As I know the *Wordpress* has `is_home()` function to determine home page.
In *YII* i use solution like this [Yii check if homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341791/yii-check-if-homepage)

In *CI*, templates actually, i faced many times with necessity of it. For example, adding some css classes in tag `<body>`.

All what i found http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/194637/#916899
Can anybody help me or write own solution?

Thank in advance

Comment: Well, I would suggest defining to yourself what "home" means.  Is it a request URI of '/' or some other URI. If so, it should be quite simple to check the request URI to see if it matches.

Comment: no offence but Laravel makes this silly things so easier.... it probably has the best router mechanism among php frameworks. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$this->router->fetch_class()` to get the current controller and `$this->router->fetch_method()` to get the method too if needed.

So similar to the Yii example you linked to, you could do something like

```
$is_home = $this->router->fetch_class() === 'name_of_home_controller' ? true : false;
```

Or to match method too

```
$is_home = ($this->router->fetch_class() === 'name_of_home_controller' && $this->router->fetch_method() === 'name_of_home_method') ? true : false;
```

This way even if the page url is http://yoursite.com/ (assuming the home controller+method is the default), http://yoursite.com/home_controller/, http://yoursite.com/something/that/routes/to/home/controller/, etc, as long as it's calling that controller, it'll set $is_home to true.

Edit: Also you can use `($this->router->fetch_class() === $this->router->default_controller)` if you don't want to explicitly state the home controller and it's set to the default controller.

Update for CI v3:
`$this->router->fetch_class()` and `$this->router->fetch_method()` were deprecated in CI v3. Use `$this->router->class` and `$this->router->method` instead.

Answer (score 21):

I just wanted to add my answer here as the other method doesn't work with my heavily modified version of CI.

This snippet is what I use to detect if we are on the homepage

```
if (!$this->uri->segment(1)) {
    // We are on the homepage
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->uri->uri_string() == ''){ 
echo"You are on homepage"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a custom helper create one; otherwise inside any of your custom helper file just paste any of the following code snippets and you should be able to use `is_home()` from any location in Codeigniter.

```
function is_home()
{
   $CI =& get_instance();
   return (!$CI->uri->segment(1))? TRUE: FALSE;
}
```

OR

```
function is_home()
{
  $CI =& get_instance();
  return (strtolower($CI->router->fetch_class()) === $CI->router->default_controller  && $CI->router->fetch_method() === 'index') ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For better answer you should cover 2 routes for home page:

I assumes there is default controller like this in **routes.php**:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

- Your home page **without** default controller name(like:
  yoursite.com)
- Your home page **with** controller name(like:
  yoursite.com/home)

  ```
  if(!$this->uri->segment(1) || $this->uri->segment(1)=='home'){ 
      // YOU ARE ON THE HOME
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply

```
public function name_of_home_method()
    {
        $data['is_home'] = true;
    }
```